Artisan command showing no output on live server
First of all, i have seen other posts with similar title but 1. they're old, 2. none of them worked. I have also searched other places, like laracast
So, my problem is that, I have built a website in laravel 11, installed breeze, worked perfectly fine. But when I uploaded into the live server, done with composer install (worked completely file) and then run php artisan key:generate I am getting no output (the command isn't even working) and all artisan command are same.
PHP v8.2, Laravel 11.

Here, as you can see, composer install went well without any errors (right side), but artisan commands not working (left side).

Firstly, if you found some other links that weren't helpful, it could be useful to post them so that readers know what you eliminated. Secondly, that screen-dump seems to have about 90 lines of text split across two screens. It would be good if you could edit the post to show just the command-lines to do with key generation in a pre-formatted text-block (ie delimited by triple-back-ticks). I realise that, with no error output, the command-line output is not clearly helpful.


All of those posts are outdated and didn't work for my case, what am I supposed to do I didn't know.
The screen shot shows that (right) everything installed successfully and (left) no artisan command working,

